# Triangle - What is the length of the hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Triangle ABC has a right angle at corner C. It has a height from C to a point D on side |AB|. If |CD|=5 and |AD|=7 then what is the length of the hypotenuse? (|AB|=?)

Correct Answer: 74/7

I have tried solving the question above by the help of the law of cosines and sines, pythagoras theorm and uniform triangles but without much success. I always tend to get to many unknown variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: right $\triangle$-s ACD and ACB are similar, since they share angle a.  Therefore, $|AD|/|CD| = |AC|/|BC|.

Comment: @IGotAQuestion Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Draw a picture.  You just need similar triangles.  $ABC,ACD,$ and $CBD$ are similar.  $\frac {BD}{DC}=\frac {CD}{AD}=\frac 57$ so $BD=\frac {25}7$ and $AB=AD+BD=7+\frac {25}7=\frac {74}7$

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the height, $CD$, will be perpendicular to side $AB$.  You can use Pythagorean Theorem to find length $AC$.  Hint:  Can you find the angle $\angle CBA$?  This will help you.

Comment: How can you know that the height CD will be perpendicular to AB? It seems to me to be an anjustified assumption.

Comment: The height (or altitude) of a triangle referenced to side $b$ must be perpendicular to $b$.  You could also look at the other answers.  There are probably many ways of solving it.